# How can I quickly convert an array of numeral characters into an integer?

Tags: delphi, performance

Situation: a whole number saved as hex in a byte array(TBytes). Convert that number to type integer with less copying, if possible without any copying.

here's an example:

```
array = ($35, $36, $37);
```

This is '5', '6', '7' in ansi. How do I convert it to 567(=$273) with less trouble?

I did it by copying twice. Is it possible to be done faster? How?

Comment: if you post your code then we may see how to improve it.

Comment: what is the max length of the hex string? with no limit, it will overflow integers of any size

Comment: What do you mean by "saved as hex"? Please post some code.

Comment: Where's that HEX coming from and why do you thing it's HEX? `TBytes` is a very unlikely data type to store HEX, `String` or `AnsiString` would be much more likely since HEX is nothing but TEXTUAL representation for binary data, using the base-16 notation.

Comment: +1 now that the question is comprehensible!

Comment: Your example doesn't match your text. That array doesn't contain a "number saved as hex." It contains characters representing the *decimal* value 567, which when written in hexadecimal is 273. You're confused because the values of those three characters was written in code using hexadecimal notation, but the *numeric values* of those three bytes has nothing to do with the notation. You could have written `$36` or `54` or `Ord('6')` and they'd all give you the same thing.

Comment: Although not relevant to the question as it is phrased here, are you sure performance is an issue (even remotely)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **LookUp Table** instead HexToInt...

This procedure works only with AnsiChars and of course no error checking is provided!

```
var
  Table        :array[byte]of byte;

procedure InitLookupTable;
var
  n:            integer;
begin
  for n := 0 to Length(Table) do
    case n of
      ord('0')..ord('9'): Table[n] := n - ord('0');
      ord('A')..ord('F'): Table[n] := n - ord('A') + 10;
      ord('a')..ord('f'): Table[n] := n - ord('a') + 10;
    else Table[n] := 0;
    end;
end;

function HexToInt(var hex: TBytes): integer;
var
  n:            integer;
begin
  result := 0;
  for n := 0 to Length(hex) -1 do
    result := result shl 4 + Table[ord(hex[n])];
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function BytesToInt(const bytes: TBytes): integer;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  result := 0;
  for i := 0 to high(bytes) do
    result := (result shl 4) + HexToInt(bytes[i]);
end;
```

As PA pointed out, this will overflow with enough digits, of course.  The implementation of HexToInt is left as an exercise to the reader, as is error handling.

Comment: ok, here's an example: array = ($35, $36, $37);. This is '5', '6', '7' in ansi. How do I convert it to 567(=$273) with less trouble? I tried your implementation and it does not do that. It's reasonable, I couldn't explain it well. Could you help me?

Comment: It will never outnumber the size of a word, but I can do that check easily. The problem is performing the operation above as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
function CharArrToInteger(const Arr: TBytes): integer;
var
  s: AnsiString;
begin
  SetLength(s, length(Arr));
  Move(Arr[0], s[1], length(s));
  result := StrToInt(s);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: TBytes;
begin
  a := TBytes.Create($35, $36, $37);
  Caption := IntToStr(CharArrToInteger(a));
end;
```

If you know that the string is null-terminated, that is, if the final character in the array is 0, then you can just do

```
function CharArrToInteger(const Arr: TBytes): integer;
begin
  result := StrToInt(PAnsiChar(@Arr[0]));
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: TBytes;
begin
  a := TBytes.Create($35, $36, $37, 0);
  Caption := IntToStr(CharArrToInteger(a));
end;
```

The most natural approach, however, is to use an array of characters instead of an array of bytes! Then the compiler can do some tricks for you:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: TCharArray;
begin
  a := TCharArray.Create(#$35, #$36, #$37);
  Caption := IntToStr(StrToInt(string(a)));
end;
```

Comment: This is how I did it at first place. I found the solution in the third answer, which for some reason got deleted. :( But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be any faster than that ;-)

```
function HexToInt(num:pointer; size:Cardinal): UInt64;
var i: integer;
    inp: Cardinal absolute num;
begin
  if(size > SizeOf(Result)) then Exit;
  result := 0;
  for i := 0 to size-1 do begin
    result := result shl 4;
    case(PByte(inp+i)^) of
      ord('0')..ord('9'): Inc(Result, PByte(inp+i)^ - ord('0'));
      ord('A')..ord('F'): Inc(Result, PByte(inp+i)^ - ord('A') + 10);
      ord('a')..ord('f'): Inc(Result, PByte(inp+i)^ - ord('a') + 10);
    end;
  end;
end;
function fHexToInt(b:TBytes): UInt64; inline;
begin
  Result:=HexToInt(@b[0], Length(b));
end;

...
b:TBytes = ($35, $36, $37);
HexToInt(@b[0], 3);
fHexToInt(b);
```

Comment: a lookup table would be faster, in the classic trade of memory for speed. But your solution looks correct to me and that's what counts.

Comment: moz is correct, a lookup table and unrolled loop by two chars would be faster. Code generated will be also faster with HexToInt(num: PByteArray; size: cardinal) because the absolute trick pass num to the stack whereas a direct PByteArray will leave it in a register, and num^[i] will use fast lea access. For a faster hex to bin routine, using a lookup table, see our hextobin() function available at http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynCommons.pas